# Formatting date in a json object obtained from scala form to insert into MongoDb

Tags: json, mongodb, forms, scala, date

I have been trying to convert the results from a [scala form](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms) (mapped to a class model) to a `json object` in order to insert this data into a (Mongo database) collection. I'm using the *Play Framework* with the *ReactiveMongo Plugin* (enabling JSON rather than BSON). The models and form looks like this:

```
   case class LastVisit(selection: String = "", date: Option[Date] = None) extends ReadAndWriteTrait

   case class AdminM(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], adminCreatedId: Option[Int], dateCreated: Option[Date], adminModifiedId: Option[Int], lastModified: Option[Date]) extends ReadAndWriteTrait

   case class MyClass(usrId: Option[BSONObjectID] = None, numOfVisits: Option[Int] = None, lastVisit_e: Option[LastVisit] = None, admin_e: Option[AdminM]) extends SuperVarT with ReadAndWriteTrait

   object MyClass extends SuperFormT with ReadAndWriteTrait {

     implicit val lastVisitFormat: OFormat[LastVisit] = Json.format[LastVisit]
     implicit val adminMFormat: OFormat[AdminM] = Json.format[AdminM]
     implicit val myClassFormat: OFormat[MyClass] = Json.format[MyClass]

     val form = Form(
       mapping(
         "usrId" -> optional(
            text.transform(str2bson, bson2str)
         ),
         "numOfVisits" -> optional(number),
         "lastVisit_e" -> optional(mapping(
            "selection" -> nonEmptyText,
            "date" -> optional(date)
         )(LastVisit.apply)(LastVisit.unapply)),
         "admin_e" -> optional(mapping(
             "_id" -> ignored(Option.empty[BSONObjectID]),
            "adminCreatedId" -> optional(number),
            "dateCreated" -> optional(date),
            "adminModifiedId" -> optional(number),
            "lastModified" -> optional(date).transform(date2Date, date2NowDate)
         )(AdminM.apply)(AdminM.unapply))
       )(MyClass.apply)(MyClass.unapply)
     )

     trait ReadAndWriteTrait {

       implicit val dateRead: Reads[Date] = (__ \ "$date").read[Long].map { 
          date => new Date(date)
       }

       implicit val dateWrite: Writes[Date] = new Writes[Date] {
         def writes(date: Date): JsValue = Json.obj(
            "$date" -> date.getTime
         )
       }

     }
```

Frustratingly the `lastVisit_e.date` field is being inserted into the database as a type `Long` number instead of an `ISODate("date here")` - which in Json is done with `Json.obj(s"$$date" -> JsNumber(dateLong here))` as [the documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/json/overview.html) states. Here is an `Action` function that I am routing to which will be used to update the data from the form to the *Mongo Collection*. I have just customised it to give me an output so that I can see that the date is not formatting correctly:

```
  def updateFromForm(collName: String, oId: Option[BSONObjectID], activeTabIdx: Int = 0) = Action.async { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>


    MyClass.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errorForm => Future.successful(Ok("TODO")),
      data => {

        /*
        // todo - uncomment when formatting is correct
        val doc = apiC.prepareData(data) // function used to transform/prepare data
        update(collName, oId, doc, activeTabIdx)(request) // function to be called to update db collection
        */

        val doc = Json.toJson(doc) // for test purposes
        Future(Ok(doc.toString())) // for test purposes
      }
    )

  }
```

This is the typical response that I get:

```
   {
      "usrId":{
         "$oid":"5a28258d9830b7614f566cc7"
      },
     "numOfVisits":5,
     "lastVisit_e":{
        "selection":"departure date",
        "date":1496271600000
      }
   }
```

`usrId` is outputting correctly (as `$oid: "5a28258d9830b7614f566cc7"`) but `lastVisit_e.date` is appearing as a `Long` number. How can I get this right? If there's any clarification required please let me know. Many thanks.

Comment: There is nothing in your question indicating that the persistence code could in anyway resolve the JSON implicits, just that the controller binding the form could.

Comment: @cchantep - thanks. So that isn't the solution if you think but then I can only assume that the reason that the `BSONObjectId` formats correctly to `"$oId":"5a28258d9830b7614f566cc7"` is due to the transform applied on the form, i.e. `"usrId" -> optional(text.transform(str2bson, bson2str))`. If this is the case then I am not sure how to do this given that I can obtain a date type from the database directly but not when attempting to bind the data to the form, i.e. `transform[B](f1: T => B, f2: B => T)`